# "Undergraduate graduation research assistant"?

Tags: graduate-school, cv, undergraduate, research-undergraduate

I have a question regarding on how to list this specific activity in undergraduate school.

I have helped many students (for free) in my undergraduate school with their graduation research by guiding them, reviewing their work and making sure everything is correct.

How do I list this in my CV?

Comment: How did you "guide" them and make sure "everything is correct" if you were still undergraduate by yourself?

Comment: I suspect many readers of whatever you write will be looking for how what you're describing is different (and worth mentioning) from the typical case of a strong subject-matter student (e.g. one who is planning to attend graduate school) tutoring friends, dorm-mates, friends of friends (e.g. a friend of yours recommended seeing you for help about some topic), etc. -- activities that nearly every such student (at least in my experience) partakes in as an undergraduate.

Comment: What is "graduation research" in your context.  I am not at all familiar with this term.

Answer (score 3):

You don't list this on your CV.

The only items that belong on your CV are accomplishments, as determined by 3rd parties. For example, work history as evaluated by employers (or paid clients, if you were, for example a consultant), educational history as determined by a diploma granted by a university, publication history as determined worthy by peer-review, etc.

Any item for which you evaluate yourself does not belong on your CV, and that includes help you gave fellow undergraduate students and which you consider valuable. This would also include self-published books (ie vanity presses), articles in predatory journals, etc.

If we all listed on our CVs every instance of helping someone out, every academic CV would be hundreds of pages long.

Comment: Good advice here. Such things are better mentioned in letters of recommendation by faculty members.

Answer (score -1):

Graduation research might be the uncommon term for this. That being said, you can just list that and explain what you mean by that term or use the alternative term that is more common. You do not need to use your university term and there is no rule that you can't have the explanation in your CV.

Answer (score -1):

I would first choose a common term for whatever it was you did. It's not clear exactly what that was. Maybe "editor", maybe something else. "Research assistant" doesn't seem to fit. Also "graduation research" isn't a common phrase. Do you mean you helped them with their undergraduate dissertation or final project?  If so, you might want to be sure that this is OK to do before listing it!

I was a statistical consultant for people doing their PhD dissertations, but I made sure to tell each of them that they had to get permission from their committee.  This was rarely a problem.

Then, I would describe what you did.